# Building Loosely coupled JavaScript modules, am I overkilling the design with DI?

Tags: javascript, typescript, client-side

I'm currently starting to develop a portion of my site that will require a moderate amount of JavaScript and I wanted to separate and write it as efficient as possible. (I had a JS 2010 mentality and I'm trying to upgrade myself to 2016)

There is no need for a framework (such as Angular 2 yet). So I decided to go with Webpack, and Typescript 1.8 w/(ES2015+).

In the server-side I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5, and I'm heavily biased in the way I build apps at the server: I use Dependency Injection for almost everything.

So I kind of applied that same mentality to the client side, and ended up with this:
In the client-side I don't know if I'm overkilling this class (It needs more separation):

```
    export class Match {
    winnerRoundMsg: string;
    acceptMsgSelector: JQuery; //$("#js-accept-message")
    currentMatchSelector: JQuery;
    matchResultSelector: JQuery; // $("#js-match-result-message")
    scorePlayerInput: JQuery; //$('.js-score-player input[type="button"]')
    scoreOpponentPlayerInput: JQuery;
    avatarImgSelector : JQuery;
    opponentNameSelector: JQuery;
    rejectBtn: JQuery;
    acceptScoreSelector: JQuery; //$("#js-accept-score");
    globalChatAreaSelector : JQuery;
    matchUpdatesSelector: JQuery;
    sendReceiveSelector: JQuery;

    score : Array<number>;

    constructor(winnerRoundMsg: string, acceptMsgSelector: JQuery, currentMatchSelector: JQuery,
        matchResultSelector: JQuery, scorePlayerInput: JQuery, scoreOpponentPlayerInput: JQuery,
        avatarImgSelector: JQuery, opponentNameSelector: JQuery, acceptScoreSelector: JQuery,
        globalChatAreaSelector: JQuery, matchUpdatesSelector: JQuery, sendReceiveSelector: JQuery
    ) {

        //Bind everything here. 

        this.winnerRoundMsg = winnerRoundMsg;
        this.acceptMsgSelector =  acceptMsgSelector;
        this.currentMatchSelector =  currentMatchSelector;
        this.matchResultSelector =  matchResultSelector;
        this.scorePlayerInput =   scorePlayerInput;
        this.scoreOpponentPlayerInput =  scoreOpponentPlayerInput;
        this.avatarImgSelector = avatarImgSelector;
        this.opponentNameSelector = opponentNameSelector;
        this.rejectBtn = $("#js-reject-btn");
        this.acceptScoreSelector = acceptScoreSelector;
        this.globalChatAreaSelector = globalChatAreaSelector;
        this.matchUpdatesSelector = matchUpdatesSelector;
        this.sendReceiveSelector = sendReceiveSelector;
    }

    loser() {

       this.matchResultSelector.removeClass("hidden");
       this.matchResultSelector.html(this.winnerRoundMsg + this.opponentNameSelector.html());
    }

    nextMatch(encryptedCurrentMatch: string, playerName: string, mediaPath: string,
            isOpponentUnknown : boolean) {

        this.acceptMsgSelector.addClass("hidden");
        this.matchResultSelector.html("");
        this.scorePlayerInput.remove("btn-info");
        this.currentMatchSelector.val(encryptedCurrentMatch);
        this.avatarImgSelector.attr("alt", playerName);
        this.avatarImgSelector.attr("src", mediaPath);

        //If Opponent is known enable all the inputs
        //otherwise disable them.

        this.scorePlayerInput.prop("disabled", isOpponentUnknown);
        this.scoreOpponentPlayerInput.prop("disabled", isOpponentUnknown);

        this.resetAcceptBtn();
        //ResetAcceptBtn();
        //Enables the submission
        // SwitchSubmission(true);
        //matchServer.setupNowPlaying(encryptedTourneyId, encryptedMatchId);
    }


    receiveScore(scoreCsv : Int32Array) {

        for (var i = 0, len = scoreCsv.length; i < len; i++) {
            const selector = $(this.scoreOpponentPlayerInput).eq(i);
            if (scoreCsv[i] !== 0) {
                selector.addClass("btn-info");
            } else {
                selector.removeClass("btn-info");
            }


        }
    }


    receiveTournamentGlobalMessage(message, playerName) {
        this.globalChatAreaSelector.append(`<p><b>${playerName}:</b> ${message} </p>`);

    }

    rejectScore() {
        //encryptedMatchId = $("#EncryptedCurrentMatch").val();
        //custom.server.rejectScore(encryptedMatchId);
        this.acceptMsgSelector.html("@Localization.Language.Area_Tournament_NowPlaying_Rejected_Score");
        this.acceptMsgSelector.removeClass("hidden");
        this.rejectBtn.remove();

    }

    resetAcceptBtn() {
        this.acceptScoreSelector.prop("disabled", false);
        this.acceptScoreSelector.val("@Localization.Language.Area_Tournament_NowPlaying_Accept_Score");
        this.acceptScoreSelector.addClass("btn-info");
        this.acceptScoreSelector.removeClass("btn-warning");
    }


    receiveMatchUpdate(message) {
        const ihtml = this.matchUpdatesSelector.html();
        this.matchUpdatesSelector.html(`<p>${message}</p>${ihtml}`);
    }


    sendScore() : Array<number> {

        this.sendReceiveSelector.html("@Localization.Language.Area_Tournament_NowPlaying_SignalSending");

        this.score = new Array(); //Neutralize
        var score = this.score;
        this.scorePlayerInput.each((index) => {
            if ($(this).hasClass("btn-info")) {
                score.push(1);
            } else {
                score.push(0);
            }
        });
        return this.score;
    }


    //Checks if the current user has received the submission
    signalReceived() {
        this.sendReceiveSelector.html("@Localization.Language.Area_Tournament_NowPlaying_SignalSent");
        setTimeout(() =>  {
                this.sendReceiveSelector.html("");
            },
            5000);
    }

    switchSubmission(on : boolean) {
        if (typeof (on) !== "boolean")
            return;
        this.scorePlayerInput.prop("disabled", !on);
        this.acceptScoreSelector.prop("disabled", !on);
    }


    winner() {
        this.matchResultSelector.removeClass("hidden");
        this.matchResultSelector.html("Congratulations! You are the winner of this round!");
    }

}
```

All the selectors I'm injecting them into the class. Through this I achieve a loosely coupled design (except from JQuery), but I don't know if this is overkill.

Comment: Uh, does the class have any other methods? If no, then you should use a plain object literal and nothing like that constructor.

Comment: @Bergi: Yes, it does have other methods, let me update the original post.

Comment: This also seems to be working: http://inversify.io/

Comment: I think that what I may end up doing is to remove redundant selectors, and define a separate JavaScript file with all the elements and pass them to the constructor.

Comment: Nope. I think it will be better to delete the parameters and define them inside the constructor. And if I ever need to reuse the code, then I adapt it to this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

> In the client-side I don't know if I'm overkilling this class (

Definitely an overkill in my opinion. Feels like [polyglot prorgramming gone wrong](https://medium.com/@basarat/issues-with-polyglot-programming-8f9ba0bfcb47).

Rather I would focus on seperate as much *logic* away from UI and then leaving the UI as just in imitation of the data state.

Comment: Hahahha. Thanks. How would you handle the class and id selectors? Do I just embed them inside the JS functions?

Comment: `id selectors` : I would be very tempted to move to a modern framework so you don't couple UI with data too much. As frameworks go React *is very very lightweight*. `How would you handle the class and id selectors` If I had to I would create the class with these passed in (like DI) but not use a DI framework :)

Comment: Thanks!  "If I had to I would create the class with these passed in (like DI) but not use a DI framework" that's what I'm doing right now, do you think it's manageable?

Comment: Pure jquery isn't very manageable in the long run. But yes, better than alternatives 

Comment: Yup. I'm trying to get as far away from it as possible. The little detail is that I'm using SignalR and that is what it powers it.

Comment: @Myself: This is something that could work: https://github.com/rovisys/signal-arr